# php redirecting to other folder

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to make a webshop for a school assingment with html/php. I want to redirect after logging in to a page in another  folder.
when you log in, you get redirected to:  249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/client/249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/home.php
while it should just redirect to: 249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/home.php
how do I fix this? I'm a complete novice with html and php so I might need some explaining of the basics...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Categorie</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="clientlogin.php" method="post">
Vul je gebruikersnaam in:<br />
<input type="text" name="gabrnaam" /><br />
<br/>
<input type="text" name="wachtwoord" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Verzend" />
</form>

<?php
$username=1;
$password=1;
if(isset($_POST["gabrnaam"]))
{
    if(isset($_POST["wachtwoord"]))
    {
    $username= $_POST["gabrnaam"];
    $password= $_POST["wachtwoord"];
    $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","250252","250252myadmin")
    or die("Fout: Er is geen verbinding met de MySQL-server tot  stand gebracht!");
    mysql_select_db("250252",$mysql)
    or die("Fout: Het openen van de database is mislukt!");
    $resultaat = mysql_query("SELECT nickname, wachtwoord FROM klantgegevens WHERE nickname = '$username' and wachtwoord='$password'",$mysql)
    or die("De query op de database is mislukt!");
    mysql_close($mysql)
    or die("Het verbreken van de verbinding met de MySQL-server is mislukt!");
    while(list($nickname,$wachtwoord)=mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
    {
    header("Location: 249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/home.php");
    }
}
else
{
    echo "U heeft uw wachtwoord niet ingevuld";
}
}
else
{
    echo "u heeft uw gebruikersnaam niet ingevuld";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `header("Location: http://249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/home.php");`

Comment: `header("Location: /home.php);`

Comment: Thanks, turns out I'm blind....

Comment: Also, @Raiding_rider, I would suggest in the future to **never, EVER** place usernames and passwords to a database (even if it is 'only' local) anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://249471.fiorettileerling.nl/po3/home.php');
```

or

```
header('Location:home.php');
```

just do this add home.php